# My merge sort program written in Java is not working?

Tags: java, data-structures, mergesort

I'm trying to create my simply merge sort program which is completely written in Java trying to sort out. Please let me know, What's wrong here?

mergeSort.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] list = {2, 5, 6, 7, 52, 64, 22, 10, 11, 14, 17, 18, 19};

        System.out.println("\t**BEFORE MERGE SORT**");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

        mergeSort(list);

        System.out.println("\t**AFTER MERGE SORT**");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }

    private static void mergeSort(int[] array){
        if(array.length > 1){
            int[] left = leftList(array);
            int[] right = rightList(array);

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);

            //Merging the sorted half into equal parts.
            merge(array, left, right);
        }
    }

    private static int[] leftList(int[] array){
        int size = array.length/2;
        int left[] = new int[size];

        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
        return left;
    }

    private static int[] rightList(int[] array){
        int size1 = array.length/2;
        int size2 = array.length - size1;
        int right[] = new int[size2];

        for(int i=0; i<size2; i++){
            right[i] = array[i+size1];
        }
        return right;
    }

    private static void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right){
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
            if(i2>=right.length || (i1 < left.length && left[i1] <= right[i2])){
                result[i1] = left[i1];
                i1++;
            }
            else{
                result[i2] = left[i2];
                i2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Getting the following output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.programming16.MyProgram.merge(MyProgram.java:63)
    at com.programming16.MyProgram.mergeSort(MyProgram.java:28)
    at com.programming16.MyProgram.mergeSort(MyProgram.java:24)
    at com.programming16.MyProgram.mergeSort(MyProgram.java:24)
    at com.programming16.MyProgram.main(MyProgram.java:13)
    **BEFORE MERGE SORT**
[2, 5, 6, 7, 52, 64, 22, 10, 11, 14, 17, 18, 19]
```

***HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!***

Comment: Which line is line 63?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough checks for your indices while trying to merge. You need to make sure both the right and left index are in the suitable range (less then the size of the array) of the array when doing the comparison. If one of the indexes is not in the suitable range, then we know we are finished with that array and we do not have to do any more comparisons since we just have to add the remaining numbers from the other array. Try something like this:

```
private static void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right){
    int i1 = 0; //left index
    int i2 = 0; //right index
    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        if (i1<left.length && i2<right.length){ //We have something in both lists
            if (left[i1]<=right[i2]){  //Add from left
                result[i] = left[i1];
                i1++;
            }else{ //Add from right
                result[i] = right[i2];
                i2++;
            }
        }
        //If we get to here we know one list is empty
        //We need to figure out which one is empty
        else if (i1<left.length){//Right is empty
            result[i] = left[i1]; //Add from left
            i1++;
        }else{ //Left is empty
            result[i] = right[i2]; //Add from right
            i2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your `merge` method:

```
result[i2] = left[i2];
```

You're accessing the array `left` at index `i2`, but that index was meant for accessing array `right`. Replace it by `result[i2] = right[i2];` If you use clear variable names, you would have seen this mistake yourself.

However - your mergesort still does not work, but at least the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is solved ;-)

Comment: I agree with the variable names. Even naming them literally _rightIndex_ and _leftIndex_ would make the code a lot more readable.